# How to find Network ID

Tags: python, ip-address

I want to find the network id using the bitwise operation between ipaddress and and subnetmask in python. I want to go with this traditional method my sample code is here

```
hostname=input("Enter the IP Address: ")
print(hostname)
if hostname >= "0.0.0.0" and hostname <= "127.255.255.255":
    print("Class A")
    print("The default subnet mask is: 255.0.0.0")
    j=(hostname & 255.0.0.0)
    print("The network id is ",j)
```

Comment: [Edit] to tag what language you are using, explain what happens when this code is run, and explain why that is an incorrect or insufficient result. (It's probably because you are trying to do things with strings that don't really make sense and need to convert to integer(s) first.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are taking input, always ensure you sanitize the input.
use [ipaddress.ip_interface()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_interface) or `ipaddress.ip_network()` to make sure the input given is a valid IP first.

Also your input `hostname` is a string, so the bitwise operation will fail.

Once you use `ipaddresss.ip_address(hostname)`, you'll get an `IPv4Address` object which will allow you to check numerous properties.

There are other helper functions in `ipaddress` standard package for taking CIDR values and creating `IPvXNetwork` objects as well, maybe that's what you are looking for, check [ipaddress HOW-TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html)

It would be roughly as follows:

```
import ipaddress

try:
    inp = input("Enter the IP Address: ")
    iface = ipaddress.ip_interface(inp)
except ValueError as e:
    # crude way of handling and printing errors
    # there are elegant ways to handle and proceed
    print(e)
    exit(1)
else:
    netword_id = iface.network
    hostname = iface.ip
```

*NOTE: I made some edits to the original answer, you probably want to use `ipaddress.ip_interface()`*

Comment: okay i will try but please tell me the basic syntax for your solution

Comment: @ComicsVibe, please check the updated answer, I've also provided a link to the Python how-to section on using this `ipaddress` module, and dealing with IP addresses in general